# package org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations does not exist

Tags: jaxb, moxy

for a while now I have been trying to use the `@XmlInverseReference` annotation from Eclipselink 2.5 to unmarshall one to many relationship between classes.

When I use the annotation the import of corresponding package is generated  as shown below :

```
@XmlInverseReference(mappedBy="materialClassDescription")
public MaterialClass getMaterialClass() {
    return materialClass;
}
```

`import org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;`

Eclipselink jar is in the build path, `jaxb.properties` is maintained and works since I use it to annotate `@XmlId` on a non string field, on building however i receive the following error :

> package org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations does not exist
>   [javac] ERROR: import
>   org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.annotations.XmlInverseReference;
>   [javac]

can anybody help ...

Comment: Which version of the JDK are you using?  Is this a regular Java SE project, or are you using something like OSGi?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in a regular Java SE setup, then you just need to ensure that `eclipselink.jar` is on your classpath.  You can confirm that you are using EclipseLink 2.5 by running the following:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.Version.printVersion();
```